# Redirect https://www.example.com to https://example.com

Tags: .htaccess, http, ssl, https

I have no knowledge of writing htaccess scripts . :(

So , basically I want to redirect 
**https://www.example.com** to "https://example.com" .

I have registered only "example.com" and not "www.example.com" with CA .

This is my present script :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have `www.example.com` in your certificate, you'll never be able to redirect without getting the security warning. The SSL handshake is performed *before the request is ever sent* to the server. That means mod_rewrite will never see the request unless the browser accepts the certificate exception.

You need to purchase a certificate that handles both "www" and without.